# There is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "employee" 1

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my main table:

```
create table employee 
(
     eno SERIAL primary key,
     ename varchar(100) not null, 
     title varchar(100) not null
);
```

I want to referenced the `title` only because I've already referenced the `eno` in another table.

```
create table pay
(
     title varchar(100), 
     sal money not null, 

     foreign key(title) references employee(title)
);
```

I get an error that there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "employee" 1

Please help me. I'm having a hard time solving this error. I'm still a beginner at SQL. thanks a lot

Comment: A **foreign key** from one table (`pay`) can *only* reference the **primary key** of another table (here: column `eno` of `employee`) - you cannot just reference any arbitrary column in another table

Comment: You can reference any column (or set of columns) with a unique key.  Those don't have to be the primary key.  If the values in your `title` column are unique, you could declare that column unique and then reference it--though in general if you already have a single-column primary key, there's no good reason to use a different single-column unique key as the target for a foreign key relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of tables that may reference a given table.
Foreign keys may only reference primary keys.

Use a foreign key to `eno`:

```
create table pay
(
     eno varchar(100), 
     sal money not null, 

     foreign key(eno) references employee(eno)
);
```